# Classless addressing

Tags: networking, computer-science, addressing

> Your router has the IP address of `216.83.11.65/27`. You wish to connect
>   a new system on the network. Which of the following addresses would
>   you assign to the new system.
>
> - A: `216.83.11.45`
> - B: `216.83.11.87`
> - C: `216.83.11.95`
> - D: `216.83.11.96`

The answer is B, but I'm not sure why. Can I get a step by step breakdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your host network can chose from all the bits in the IP address, that are not used to define the network.<sup>1</sup>

So when looking at the Network Configuration you have, your network has the following range (you can use a subnet calculator to get to these values):

```
216.83.11.65 - 216.83.11.94
```

This rules out A and D, because you will need a router to get there (since the IP addresses cannot be directly reached within the network).

Your network internal broadcast address will be `216.83.11.95`. This rules out answer C, because a host cannot have the broadcast address of your network.

So, only answer B stands.

---

<sup>1</sup> I know that this might not be understandable at all. Cannot do it better. In this case please refer to Wikipedia: [Classless Inter-Domain Routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)